# avoid sql injection for dynamic columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How can I avoid SQL injection in this scenario?

```
where("(#{foo} IS NULL) OR (bar IS NULL)")
```

If I do:

```
where("(? IS NULL) OR (bar IS NULL)", 'foo')
```

Then it makes that WHERE (('foo' is null) or (bar IS NULL))

And those added quotes cause the query to not work...

Answer (score 0):

Use line bellow:

```
where("(%s IS NULL) OR (bar IS NULL)", 'foo')
```

This line works same as,

```
where("(? IS NULL) OR (bar IS NULL)", 'foo')
```

but except skip to add quote to generate query.

First one generates: `WHERE ((foo is null) or (bar IS NULL))`

Where second one generates: `WHERE (('foo' is null) or (bar IS NULL))` which occur an error.

Both formats are avoid SQL injection (in this case 2nd format generate an error) because of rails by default sanitize_sql the 2nd parameter.

Comment: Can you explain why and how this prevents SQL injection?

Comment: @Mark I have update my ans to clear your answer. It's only skip to add quote from your tried code. In this case also Rails by default avoid SQL injection from second parameter.